# Has anyone tried to search for new basic machine learning operations like convolution and pooling?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

From [Neural Architecture Search: A Survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.05377), first published in 2018:

> Moreover, common search spaces are also based on predefined building
>   blocks, such as different kinds of convolutions and pooling, but do
>   not allow identifying novel building blocks on this level; going
>   beyond this limitation might substantially increase the power of NAS.

I wonder now if somebody tried that since this was written or if anybody has some thoughts about the feasibility of this idea.